# Async/Await chaining

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, chain

Guess it's my turn to create a user at stackoverflow :)

I've tried and solve this assignment for 2 days now, i can get it to show the first two informations, but i have no idea how i access the last two...
Plus i have a slight idea, that i am doing it completely wrong...

This is what i have to do:

- Use information from this link to find the first movie in which  Luke Skywalker  appeared
- Use information from this link to find the first species, which appeared in this movie
- Use information from this link to find the planet (homeworld) for this species

Now, Implement a method `getPlanetforFirstSpeciesInFirstMovieForPerson(id){}` which for `id = 1 (Luke Skywalker)` should log this info:

Name: Luke Skywalker
First film: The Empire Strikes Back
First species: Yoda's species
Homeworld for Specie: unknown

Hints:

1. This requires you to make a number of REST-requests (using fetch), read a value from the request, and use this value to perform a new request.
2. The lists in the responses are not sorted. For this exercise it’s ok to just use the first URL in the list: Like `films[0]` will actually give you the second movie, see below:

Data:

```
"films": [
  "https://swapi.co/api/films/2/", 
  "https://swapi.co/api/films/6/", 
  "https://swapi.co/api/films/3/", 
  "https://swapi.co/api/films/1/", 
  "https://swapi.co/api/films/7/"
],
```

This is what I have so far:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const URL = "https://swapi.co/api/people/";

async function getPlanetForFirstSpeciesInFirstMovieForPersonID(id) {

    const result = await fetch(URL);

    const data = await result.json().then((nameData) => nameData.results[id]);
    const name = data.name

    const film = await fetch(data.films[id])

    const filmdata = await film.json().then((movietitle) => movietitle.title)

    console.log(name)
    console.log(filmdata)
}

getPlanetForFirstSpeciesInFirstMovieForPersonID(0).catch((e) => {

    console.log('There was an error :', e)
});
```

But I guess there has to be a cleaner and smarter way to do this.
I can do it without problems using promises the old way, but I have to use async/await.

Comment: I'm not sure what your start point should be, I assume it is 'people'.
Start with a request on the first level: https://swapi.co/api/people/

Then from there, use a for loop in results to find Luke, when you have luke's result, you will also have his 'films'.

Use a for loop to look through films link (using the rest link). 
In each films, there will be a for loop again on the species.
Compare your result with what you are looking for.
When you have it, display the result and leave.

in the end, it will be imbricated for loops with rest request and an 'if' each time

Comment: When i start i already have Luke, since i have personid=0 as my parameter in my calling function. My problem or What i cant work my head around:) Is How i jump to the different URLs. Since films is a seperate URL, species is a seperate URL etc.I dont know if a forloop would work, since theres No need to loop when i already know What index I'm searching for..

Comment: At each step, you have to answer those questions:
What can I know with my current data. What do I wan't for next step.
Then you follow the url accordingly. 

You have to understand what you are looking for before asking how.